# How to load a preexisting PrintWriter into Java?

Tags: java, file, load, printwriter

I have a txt file that I want to load into Java, and I've been trying to use

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("location/name.txt"));
```

But instead of loading the existing file, it writes over the old one and creates a new blank one. How can I load the existing file into Java?

Comment: This question makes little sense.  You can't "load a PrintWriter".  A `PrintWriter` is something for **writing** a file.  That's what the "write" in `PrintWriter` refers to.  If you want to read a text file you need to use a `Reader` of some kind.  However, since we don't know what you are *actually* trying to do, I don't think we can answer this.

Comment: If you want to read a file you need to use a Reader not a Writer.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a Reader instead of Writer.

There are various ways to read a text file in Java e.g. you can use FileReader, BufferedReader or Scanner to read a text file. Each class has its own purpose e.g. BufferedReader is used to buffer data for reading fast, and Scanner provides parsing ability.

Example using BufferedReader :

```
public class ReadFile {

     public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
      {
      File file = new File("C:\\location\\test.txt");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

      String st;
      while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(st);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
    try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("location/yourFileName.txt", true)))) {
       pw.println("what you want to write to the file");
       pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      //Exception handling goes here.
    }
```

The `FileWriter` constructor's second argument is what sets the append condition. Also, as stated in the comments(and pretty obvious) that you need a reader to **load** or **input** data.

Answer (score -3):

You can try
File f = new File(filePathString);

Comment: This does not load a text file.  Not by any stretch of the imagination.